# Como criar uma diretiva em AngularJs que crie uma máscara e não modifiquei o ng-model?

Tags: angularjs, angular, angularjs-directives, angularjs-scope

Criei uma diretiva onde a mesma serve de máscara para conta corrente, então quanto digito um valor sempre o valor mais a direita no input é o dígito da minha conta, até então beleza, está funcionando. O problema é que eu não quero alterar o valor do meu ng-model se eu informo por exemplo 123456 deve aparecer na minha view 12345-6 e no meu ng-model deve estar apenas 123456 (sem o traço). O que está acontecendo e que o meu ng-model está sendo alterado (12345-6). Alguém sabe como resolver isso??

**Na minha view está correto, a diretiva me atende**

OBS.: No canto esquerdo inferior olhe meu ng-model
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
angular.module('app').directive('contaCorrenteMask', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: "ngModel",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {           

            var _formatContaBanco = function (data) {

                if (!data)
                    return data;

                if (data.length == 1)
                    return data;

                data = data.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, "");

                var digito = data.slice(-1);
                var conta = data.slice(0, -1);
              
                return conta + '-' + digito;
            };
           
            // Send out changes from inside: 
            scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function (val) {
                scope.model = val;
                ctrl.$setViewValue(_formatContaBanco(scope.model));
                ctrl.$render();
            });
        }
    };
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Então seu problema é que você está usando o **setViewValue**.

```
ctrl.$setViewValue(_formatContaBanco(scope.model));
```

Isso faz com que o ngModel também seja atualizado, para ter o *viewValue* e *modelValue* diferentes você deve usar:

### Formata o texto do ngModel para o view

```
ngModel.$formatters.push(function(value) {
   return value.toUpperCase();
});
```

### Formata o texto do view para o ngModel

```
ngModel.$parsers.push(function(value) {
   return value.toLowerCase();
});
```

---

### Agora o seu código corrigido

```
angular.module('app').directive('contaCorrenteMask', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: "ngModel",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {           

            var _formatContaBanco = function (data) {

                if (!data)
                    return data;

                if (data.length == 1)
                    return data;

                data = data.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, "");

                var digito = data.slice(-1);
                var conta = data.slice(0, -1);
          
                return conta + '-' + digito;
            };
       
            // Send out changes from inside: 
            ctrl.$formatters.push(function (modelValue) {
                return _formatContaBanco(modelValue);
            });
        }
    };
})
```